# Key down lags Mouse in Flash with FF

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, firefox, lag

I'm trying to improve the performance of a flash game we did. It's a game very similar to GTA but for flash... This is why its important that Mouse and keyboard can be used at the same time...

But in Firefox (with the last flash version, and the last Firefox version) in some cases if you press a key (WASD) and you move the mouse, the mouse events are dispached after the keyboard events, when you release the keyboard....

I found that a lot of people are having the same problem in their own games but they couldnt solve it!

Some help plz!

Edit:

The full code is very big and i colund't find what part is the problem. But I did this class to do a test (this class is runing with the game :

```
    public function MouseAndKeyboardTest()
    {
        var stage : Stage = FW.Stage_;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);
    }

    private function KeyUp(e : KeyboardEvent)
    {
        trace("Key Up : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    private function KeyDown(e : KeyboardEvent)
    {
        trace("Key Down : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    private function MouseMove(e : MouseEvent)
    {
        trace("Mouse Move : [" + e.stageX + ", " + e.stageY + "]"   );
    }
```

and this was the trace result when you had the key down and the mouse moving at the same time, some mouse move in between and a lot after all key are up:

```
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 87
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 68
        Key Up : 65
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 65
        Key Up : 68
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 65
        Key Down : 68
        Key Up : 65
        Mouse Move : [353.65, 137.55]
        Mouse Move : [354.8, 138.4]
        Mouse Move : [354.8, 137.4]
        Mouse Move : [362.8, 135.4]
        Mouse Move : [372.9, 135.25]
        Key Down : 68
        Mouse Move : [449.9, 139.25]
        Mouse Move : [462.85, 139.35]
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Mouse Move : [479.85, 139.35]
        Mouse Move : [477.85, 139.35]
        Mouse Move : [469.85, 141.35]
        Mouse Move : [458.95, 145.2]
        Key Down : 68
        Mouse Move : [445.95, 148.2]
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Key Down : 68
        Mouse Move : [330.65, 171.55]
        Key Down : 68
        Key Up : 87
        Key Up : 68
        Mouse Move : [210, 196.2]
        Mouse Move : [207, 198.2]
        Mouse Move : [246.2, 190]
        Mouse Move : [354.2, 180]
        Mouse Move : [431.15, 173]
        Mouse Move : [323.15, 197]
        Mouse Move : [181.15, 220]
        Mouse Move : [80.15, 231]
        Mouse Move : [267.15, 203]
        Mouse Move : [186.15, 225]
        Mouse Move : [20.15, 217]
        Mouse Move : [161.15, 217]
        Mouse Move : [132.15, 223]
```

Comment: Please post code pertaining to the problem. We aren't telepathic, so we can't read your mind.

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm sorry but the code is very big, maybe 60K lines... I did a litle test.

Comment: Is being able to hit two WADS keys at once essential? There are a few ways to approach this.

Comment: It's essential for the game becouse the player must move in any direction in the game... I Don't know all the approaches for this but we calculate the direction the user must move from the keys the user pressed.

Comment: I might be able to take a look at this in depth this weekend. Regardless, your problem is one of garbage collection. You need to be at least removing the listener when keys either aren't being used, or are being used excessively.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the Plugin-container in Firefox 3.6.4 and above. By changing:

```
'dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npswf32.dll' to false
```

in the about:config from FF it solved the problem witht the mouse and the keyboard in Firefox.

But I still got the problem that I can't change that in all the Firefoxs from the game users.
The important question is that the user have no lag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to take a look at:

```
var keys:Object = {};
var keyTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

keyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, keyTimed, false, 0, true);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownManager, false, 0, true);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpManager, false, 0, true);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved, false, 0, true);

function keyTimed(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    keyTimer.stop();
    keyTimer.reset();
    if(stage.hasEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN))
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownManager);
    }
}

function keyDownManager(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keyTimer.start();
    switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case 37:
        keys['left'] = true;
        break;
        case 38:
        keys['up'] = true;
        break;
        case 39:
        keys['right'] = true;
        break;
        case 40:
        keys['down'] = true;
        break;
    }
    trace("key is down");
}

function keyUpManager(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keyTimer.stop();
    keyTimer.reset();
    switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case 37:
        keys['left'] = false;
        break;
        case 38:
        keys['up'] = false;
        break;
        case 39:
        keys['right'] = false;
        break;
        case 40:
        keys['down'] = false;
        break;
    }
    trace("key is up");
    if(!stage.hasEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN))
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownManager, false, 0, true);
    }
}

function mouseMoved(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("mouse moved");
}
```

I've specified a bounds of `1000` milliseconds for a timer that will run whenever a key is down. This will enable you to work with multiple keys, but will remove the listener once any combination of keys have been held down for `1000` milliseconds. Once any key is released, the listener is re-added and the timer reset. What this enables you to do is control the removal of the listener if someone is holding a combination of keys for a set (long in this case) amount of time.

Furthermore, I've implemented an object to store the key booleans so those properties can be utilized inside an `ENTER_FRAME` or something similar for movement.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I just did this test you suggested but did not work. : (
I'm goint to try moving on enter frame

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Firefox 3.6.14 and I couldn't replicate your error. But I created a small class, so you can test it for yourself. Does it work as you want? To use it, create a new project, using this class as Main. You should have an object that you can move with WASD and an aim, that you move with the mouse. You can move on any direction, and the mouse at the same time. Please post your results.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var keys:Array = new Array();
        private var hero:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var aim:Sprite = new Sprite();
        public function Main():void {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

            // create the objects for testing
            hero.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            hero.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            hero.graphics.endFill();
            hero.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            hero.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            stage.addChild(hero);

            aim.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            aim.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
            aim.graphics.moveTo(0, -10);
            aim.graphics.lineTo(0, 10);
            aim.graphics.moveTo(-10, 0);
            aim.graphics.lineTo(10, 0);
            aim.x = hero.x + hero.width / 2;
            aim.y = hero.y + hero.height / 2;
            stage.addChild(aim);
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void {
            if (keys[65]) hero.x -= 5;
            if (keys[68]) hero.x += 5;
            if (keys[87]) hero.y -= 5;
            if (keys[83]) hero.y += 5;
        }

        private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
            aim.x = e.stageX;
            aim.y = e.stageY;
        }
        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
        private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In the game I have two parts, one in which you can walk in the street and another in which you can't walk becouse you are in a house. 

I tested what you suggest in a new proyect without the game and it works. When added to the game, if I'm on the street walking works just like always, but at home it works great!!

The problem that I have is in the street with a lot of cars, people and the city.

I add the link of the application: http://apps.facebook.com/auto-hustle

Comment: I was checking the game and I don't know if you resolved it but it works ok for me. But if you are still having this issue, and **only** on Firefox, I suggest you run a profiler in the application. You can run anyone, but I recommend this one: http://code.google.com/p/flashpreloadprofiler/ . With this application, you should be able to spot any memory leak or hidden event listeners that are not being released, so you have a chance to catch the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the key down event for say 'W' you could save that fact in a variable, say boolean wKeyIsDown. Then cancel the event to stop recieving the event. Then when w is up change your wKeyIsDown variable to false and cancel the event again. You don't constantly need to know of the occurrence.

It might be helpful to see how you are using the events. Your movement logic may be flawed.

Comment: Hi dubbeat thanks for your answer.

If I dont understand wrong your sugestion, this wouldn't allow me to hear more then one key at the time, becouse i will cancel the event as soon as I receive a Key_donw event.

It's essential for the game that the player can move in any direction.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: what I was suggesting was that when you recieve a down event store it in an array then cancel the current event for that button. then when you recieve an up event add back the down event and change the value in the array. The benefit of this I suppose is that in your code for moving you are not checking the conditions of events but checking the value of the variables you set. Again, it would be helpful to see your movement code

Answer (score 0):

Try using weak references.

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove, false, 0, true):
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp, false, 0, true):
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDown, false, 0, true):
```

Notice the last parameter, regarding weak references, must be set to true.

ps: bienvenido a stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Hi Veehmot thanks for your answer.

I did what you advised me but the end result was the same. I was hoping this would solve my problem.

Comment: Weak references only make a difference when the object that's attached to the listener is being removed. That's why there's no effect.